# Python - Need to parse all the elements of a number of XML files. Fastest parser?

Tags: python, xml, pickle

I have hundreds of small (on the order of kilobytes) XML files whose information I need to use at run-time.  All of the data in these XML files is useful to me, not just some.

At runtime, as I hit the need for information from one of these I could construct an ElementTree, parse the XML file, and iterate over it recursively - resulting in a python object that I keep around and throw away the DOM.  But if I'm going to ship the XML files and parse them at runtime I'm wondering if I ought to look at a forward-only parser rather than a DOM-based parser.

Given that this data is static at build-time, perhaps I ought to even parse the XML into python objects, pickle them, ship 'em, and un-pickle them at runtime.  I haven't used pickling yet - would it allow for the user of dictionaries, etc?  Or is it meant for very basic data structures?

Hope I'm being clear - I have a lot of data in XML files that I'll use at runtime.  Wondering what would be fastest (at run-time) to access this data.  I don't mind leaving it in memory at runtime once it's been accessed once.

Can share an example of the data if that would be helpful (whether in XML format or what I'd want the python class/object look like)...

EDIT: A few people have mentioned lxml.  I'll go look into that.  Anyone have links to parsing data from xml using lxml versus un-pickling?

Comment: Is lxml too slow to use for your use case?

Comment: According to http://lxml.de/performance.html , lxml can parse at around 100MB/s.

Comment: When you're parsing lots of small files, the speed of the parser in Mb/sec is usually irrelevant: it's the initialization (per-document) cost that matters. Any data on that?

Answer (score 3):

`lxml` is the fastest XML parser for Python.

I would keep it in XML format unless size is an issue. Combine your XML files together if speed is an issue.

Depending on your data, putting your information into an SQLite database might be a good choice as well.

Comment: SQLite has the added perk that you can let SQLite enforce data consistency (primary keys, foreign keys, etc.) which is good for preventing certain classes of bugs. If your data can reasonably be transformed from XML into a database structure, I would definitely consider it.

Comment: Good thought.  Turning it into a database seems like overkill at first thought, but it may not be such a bad idea.